# Ratios of random variables with weak moment condition

Tags: pr.probability, mathematical-finance

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of iid positive random variables. Assume that $X_n$ has finite $\alpha$th moment for some value $\alpha \in (0,1)$, but infinite first moment. Assume also that the reciprocal $1/X_n$ has finite moment generating function.

Define the random variable $$Y_n := \frac{X_n}{X_1 + \cdots + X_{n-1}}.$$ Is it possible for $Y_n$ to have infinite moments of all order? If so, could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: Erm... $EY_n^\alpha\le EX_n^\alpha EX_1^{-\alpha}<+\infty$ (unless I am misreading something in your post).

Answer (score 1):

Since $1/X_j$ has a finite moment generating function, the random variable $\frac 1{X_1+\dots+X_{n-1}}$ has moments of any order. Using independence, we thus have that $Y_n\in\mathbb L^p$ if and only if $X_n\in\mathbb L^p$.

In particular, $Y_n$ has finite moments of order $\alpha$ but not of order $1$.